# When install app through Testflight shows alert

Tags: testflight

When trying to install the app. A pop up shows up and reads:
Could not install {AppName}
The app can't be installed because it is invalid. Try again.

Comment: This is true for all the apps we have

Comment: Happening the same for us.

Comment: I filed a ticket with Apple and checked the status board ~30 min later. It shows "TestFlight - 1 Issue, 1 Resolved Issue". After about 1.5hr posting the question, the issue seemed fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Testflight is currently experiencing server issues.

You can check the current status here:

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

```
TestFlight - 1 Issue, 1 Resolved Issue
Issue: Today, 10:11 AM - ongoing

Some users are affected

Users are experiencing a problem with this service. We are working to resolve this issue.

Resolved Issue: 06/26/2019, 10:30 AM - Today, 3:00 AM

Some users were affected

Users experienced a problem with this service.
```